# How to identify when a function is being called using IDA?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, x86

I'm debugging a `.exe` file on Windows with IDA's debugger.

How can I identify when the code calls the `random()` function?

Answer (score 4):

While the debugger is loaded and the executable is running, double-click on the `random()` function entry in the imports tab/view to see it in the disassembler view. Then place a breakpoint on it using *Debugger -> Breakpoints -> Add breakpoint*.

Comment: (`F2` is the keyboard shortcut for placing breakpoints)