# Log functions called in IDA Pro?

Tags: ida, ida-plugin, executable, functions

When I run an exe in IDA how could I log which functions were called into a text file?

```
log.txt:
call func1
call func2
call func1
call func1
```

Not worried about indirect calls.
This is for differential analysis, to find where execution paths deviated, without manual work.
I know it won't be perfect because of the scheduling, but better than tracing by hand.

Advanced option would be to limit to given thread.

Closest answer is different: [How to identify when a function is being called using IDA?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/18654/how-to-identify-when-a-function-is-being-called-using-ida?r=SearchResults)

Comment: Hi and welcome to RE.SE. You may be looking for something like [lighthouse](https://github.com/gaasedelen/lighthouse), if I understand you correctly. Possibly [tenet](https://github.com/gaasedelen/tenet) by the same author is also or even a better match.

Comment: If you just want to trace certain files and don't need any of the debugger functions of IDA you could alternatively use `frida` respectively `frida-trace`. It is Python based and supports a lot of platforms.

Comment: I found it, built in tracing of functions, just needed to enable after main func, not the fastest but still usable, thank you! Post it as an answer and I accept it. cheer